# How to strip domain name out of a url in PHP?

Tags: php

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)
```

The above will work for:

`sub1.domain.name`,

`sub2.domain.name`,...

I want to strip the domain name only.

Comment: define "fail" -- returns false or the parsing isn't what you expect?

Comment: So what is it doing, exactly? Provide input/output examples.

Comment: It may output `sub1,domain.name`,`sub2.domain.name` while I want `domain.name`

Comment: I would expect your first example to fail--I don't believe commas are allowed in domain names.  On the second (in a quick test) the parse_url does what it is intended to do, it gives you sub2.domain.name as the host name--I don't believe parse_url is supposed to break our subdomain from that set.

Comment: @Shane,I don't mean to say this is a bug of `parse_url`,just not the proper solution for this problem

Comment: Exactly, I was just confirming for you that what you see was the expected behavior.  You will need to use something like explode('.', $url) once you have the host to break our the subdomain.

Comment: @Shane ,that's not as easy as it looks.See my comment below,there will be exceptions.

Comment: @unknown you may want to edit your question with this extra information.

Comment: Just posted an answer--check it please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Url splitting in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102447/url-splitting-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

So what you are starting with is not a URL.

The easiest solution is to make it look like a URL:

```
function get_host_from_bad_url($url)
{
 if (!$candidate_host=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)) { // deliberate assignment
     $candidate_host=parse_url('http://' . $url, PHP_URL_HOST);
 }
 return $condidate_host;
}
```

There are all sorts of other things which **might** contain a host name - but without a lot more info its hard to suggest how to parse these.

However an alternative approach would be to try to extract anything which looks like it might be a hostname (and then potentially, do a DNS check on it):

```
function strip_hosts_from_string($inp)
{
 $inp=strtolower($inp);
 $matches=preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9\-]+\.){2,}([a-z]{2,6})/',$inp);
 $hostnames=$matches[0];
 foreach ($hostnames as $x=>$host) {
       if (gethostbyname($host)==$host) {
           unset($hostnames[$x]);
       }
 }
 return $hostnames;
}
```

C.

Comment: +1,this is almost there.But I don't know if there is a more direct method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in dozens of ways. It could look like this:

```
$host = 'en.sub.domain.name';
$subdomain = implode('.', explode('.', $host, -2));
```

### EDIT:

This is not going to work with `.co.uk`, `.com.pl`, `.gov.fr` [SLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain). It seems that the easiest way to remove domain is to create an array of [TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) and [SLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain), loop through that array and if `$host` ends with some array's element then cut last n characters and break the loop.

Comment: Add a special case for when it has more than two periods, then.

Comment: @Code Duck: what if we have more than one subdomain?

Comment: I agree, that's what makes this so difficult.  The plan to create a list of valid TLDs could be the only way to be sure.

Comment: It's not applicable,there can be third level domain,fourth level domains...no limitation.

Comment: There is a finite and well defined list of 1st and 2nd level domains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this--it's a little 'wordy' but it does what you need with the information provided in comments and this will work for full URL including HTTP and without if you just have the domain.

```
$domain = 'domain1.domain2.bbc.co.uk';
$array = explode('.', $domain);
$trash = array_pop($array);
$trash = array_pop($array);

$subdomain = join('.', $array);
print $subdomain;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just take anything after the first dot, if there is more than one  dot.

```
$url=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$domain=substr($url,strpos($url,'.')+1);
```

This is a bit hacky, of course, but it works on your examples. You might wish to test to see if there were at least two .s first. If you're dealing with a url like news.bbc.co.uk it would work, but not for bbc.co.uk.