# How to make this PHP URL parsing function nearly perfect?

Tags: php, regex, url, parsing

This function is great, but its main flaw is that it doesn't handle domains ending with .co.uk or .com.au. How can it be modified to handle this?

```
function parseUrl($url) {
    $r  = "^(?:(?P<scheme>\w+)://)?";
    $r .= "(?:(?P<login>\w+):(?P<pass>\w+)@)?";
    $r .= "(?P<host>(?:(?P<subdomain>[-\w\.]+)\.)?" . "(?P<domain>[-\w]+\.(?P<extension>\w+)))";
    $r .= "(?::(?P<port>\d+))?";
    $r .= "(?P<path>[\w/-]*/(?P<file>[\w-]+(?:\.\w+)?)?)?";
    $r .= "(?:\?(?P<arg>[\w=&]+))?";
    $r .= "(?:#(?P<anchor>\w+))?";
    $r = "!$r!";

    preg_match ( $r, $url, $out );

    return $out;
}
```

To clarify my reason for looking for something other than parse_url() is that I want to strip out (possibly multiple) subdomains as well.

```
print_r(parse_url('sub1.sub2.test.co.uk'));
```

Results in:

```
Array(
[scheme] => http
[host] => sub1.sub2.test.co.uk
)
```

What I want to extract is "test.co.uk" (sans subdomains), so first using parse_url is a pointless extra step where the output is the same as the input.

Comment: Have fun maintaining that mess.  Why not just add your desired functionality on top of `parse_url()`?

Comment: `"What I want to extract is "test.co.uk" (sans subdomains), so first using parse_url is a pointless extra step where the output is the same as the input."` So, you would rather struggle with this gigantic, fragile regex, instead of using a simpler regex on the host portion?  This image comes to mind: http://media.photobucket.com/image/double%20facepalm/Selphos/Facepalm/double-facepalm.jpg

Comment: Yes, I would rather have only one function call.

Comment: Huh? Why? It's better to struggle with this huge mess then to call another, built-in, function?

Comment: Because as I demonstrated, calling the built-in function results in an output that does not resolve the problem I am trying to have addressed here.

With that in mind, wouldn't you rather go out for an ice cream cone or something than struggle to convince me that using parse_url first is worthwhile?

Comment: Wow, the fail is really strong here.  Love the attitude, good luck to you.

Comment: George, you don't understand the problem, but thanks for all the comments.

Comment: Then help me understand it.  Why is it wrong to use parse_url() to do the initial parsing and then further parsing on the `host` returned by it?  If you're only parsing a FQDN to get its root domain, why use all those subpatterns matching all possible parts of a URL?  Your statement, which I quoted above, leads me to believe this is an -- in IMO naive -- attempt at optimization.  Don't forget "premature optimization is the root of all evil."  I don't know this for certain, but it may very well be that this huge regex may perform worse than using parse_url and then a simpler regex on `host`.

Comment: Also, since these comments are not attached to an answer or question of my own, you should use @George to ensure that I get a notification about a reply.  I may be a hard-ass, but I'm a caring hard-ass. I do want to understand the situation.  You may very well have a good reason for doing this and it's just not evident to me, as yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Url splitting in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102447/url-splitting-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may or may not be of interest, but here's a regex I wrote that *mostly* conforms to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (it's actually slightly stricter, as it disallows some of the more unusual URI syntaxes):

```
~^(?:(?:(?P<scheme>[a-z][0-9a-z.+-]*?)://)?(?P<authority>(?:(?P<userinfo>(?P<username>(?:[\w.\~-]|(?:%[\da-f]{2})|[!$&'()*+,;=])*)?:(?P<password>(?:[\w.\~-]|(?:%[\da-f]{2})|[!$&'()*+,;=])*)?|(?:[\w.\~-]|(?:%[\da-f]{2})|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:)*?)@)?(?P<host>(?P<domain>(?:[a-z](?:[0-9a-z-]*(?:[0-9a-z]))?\.)+(?:[a-z](?:[0-9a-z-]*(?:[0-9a-z]))?))|(?P<ip>(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d\d|\d?\d).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d\d|\d?\d).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d\d|\d?\d).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d\d|\d?\d)))(?::(?P<port>\d+))?(?=/|$)))?(?P<path>/?(?:(?:[\w.\~-]|(?:%[\da-f]{2})|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)+/)*(?:(?:[\w.\~-]|(?:%[\da-f]{2})|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)+/?)?)(?:\?(?P<query>(?:(?:[\w.\~-]|(?:%[\da-f]{2})|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)|/|\?)*?))?(?:#(?P<fragment>(?:(?:[\w.\~-]|(?:%[\da-f]{2})|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)|/|\?)*))?$~i
```

The named components are:

```
scheme
authority
  userinfo
    username
    password
  domain
  ip
path
query
fragment
```

And here's the code that generates it (along with variants defined by some options):

```
public static function validateUri($uri, &$components = false, $flags = 0)
{
    if (func_num_args() > 3)
    {
        $flags = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    }
    
    if (is_array($flags))
    {
        $flagsArray = $flags;
        $flags = array();
        foreach ($flagsArray as $flag)
        {
            if (is_int($flag))
            {
                $flags |= $flag;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Set options.
    $requireScheme = !($flags & self::URI_ALLOW_NO_SCHEME);
    $requireAuthority = !($flags & self::URI_ALLOW_NO_AUTHORITY);
    $isRelative = (bool)($flags & self::URI_IS_RELATIVE);
    $requireMultiPartDomain = (bool)($flags & self::URI_REQUIRE_MULTI_PART_DOMAIN);
    
    // And we're away…
    
    // Some character types (taken from RFC 3986: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).
    $hex = '[\da-f]'; // Hexadecimal digit.
    $pct = "(?:%$hex{2})"; // "Percent-encoded" value.
    $gen = '[\[\]:/?#@]'; // Generic delimiters.
    $sub = '[!$&\'()*+,;=]'; // Sub-delimiters.
    $reserved = "(?:$gen|$sub)"; // Reserved characters.
    $unreserved = '[\w.\~-]'; // Unreserved characters.
    $pChar = "(?:$unreserved|$pct|$sub|:|@)"; // Path characters.
    $qfChar = "(?:$pChar|/|\?)"; // Query/fragment characters.
    
    // Other entities.
    $octet = '(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d\d|\d?\d)';
    $label = '[a-z](?:[0-9a-z-]*(?:[0-9a-z]))?';
    
    $scheme = '(?:(?P<scheme>[a-z][0-9a-z.+-]*?)://)';
    
    // Authority components.
    $userInfo = "(?:(?P<userinfo>(?P<username>(?:$unreserved|$pct|$sub)*)?:(?P<password>(?:$unreserved|$pct|$sub)*)?|(?:$unreserved|$pct|$sub|:)*?)@)?";
    $ip = "(?P<ip>$octet.$octet.$octet.$octet)";
    if ($requireMultiPartDomain)
    {
        $domain = "(?P<domain>(?:$label\.)+(?:$label))";
    }
    else
    {
        $domain = "(?P<domain>(?:$label\.)*(?:$label))";
    }
    $host = "(?P<host>$domain|$ip)";
    $port = '(?::(?P<port>\d+))?';
    
    // Primary hierarchical URI components.
    $authority = "(?P<authority>$userInfo$host$port(?=/|$))";
    $path = "(?P<path>/?(?:$pChar+/)*(?:$pChar+/?)?)";
    
    // Final bits.
    $query = "(?:\?(?P<query>$qfChar*?))?";
    $fragment = "(?:#(?P<fragment>$qfChar*))?";
    
    // Construct the final pattern.
    $pattern = '~^';
    
    // Only include scheme and authority if the path is not relative.
    if (!$isRelative)
    {
        if ($requireScheme)
        {
            // If the scheme is required, then the authority must also be there.
            $pattern .= $scheme . $authority;
        }
        else if ($requireAuthority)
        {
            $pattern .= "$scheme?$authority";
        }
        else
        {
            $pattern .= "(?:$scheme?$authority)?";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Disallow that optional slash we put in $path.
        $pattern .= '(?!/)';
    }
    
    // Now add standard elements and terminate the pattern.
    $pattern .= $path . $query . $fragment . '$~i';
    
    // Finally, validate that sucker!
    $components = array();
    $result = (bool)preg_match($pattern, $uri, $matches);
    if ($result)
    {
        // Filter out all of the useless numerical matches.
        foreach ($matches as $key => $value)
        {
            if (!is_int($key))
            {
                $components[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

What's wrong with the built-in [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url)?

Comment: `parse_url` is too lenient with malformed URLs, which the OP might not want.

Comment: Actually, the reason is I want to strip out all subdomains as well.

Comment: Hmmm, since parse_url gives you the hostname, why not then write a (simpler) expression to split the subdomains and extension from that?

Comment: @Fo Why don't you use parse_url for the initial parsing and perform further parsing on the hostname it returns?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this bit:

```
(?P<extension>\w+)
```

With:

```
(?P<extension>\w+(?:\.\w+)?)
```

Where there `(?:`...`)` part is a non-capturing group, with the `?` making it optional.

I'd probably go a step further and change that bit to this:

```
(?P<extension>[a-z]{2,10}(?:\.[a-z]{2,10})?)
```

Since the extension don't contain number or underscore, and are usually just 2/3 letters (I think .museum is longest, at 6... so 10 is probably a safe maximum).

If you do that, you might want a case-insensitive flag added, (or put A-Z in also).

Based on your comment, you want to make the subdomain part of the match 'lazy' (only match if it has to), and thus allow the extension to capture both parts.

To do that, simply add a `?` to the end of the quanitifer, changing:

```
(?P<subdomain>[-\w\.]+)
```

to

```
(?P<subdomain>[-\w\.]+?)
```

And (in theory - haven't got PHP handy to test) that will only make the subdomain longer if it has to, so should allow the extension group to match appropriately.

---

**Update:**
Ok, assuming you've extracted the full hostname already (using parse_url as suggested in other Q/comments), try this for matching subdomain, domain, and extension parts:

```
^(?P<subdomains>(?:[\w-]+\.)*?)(?P<domain>[\w-]+(?P<extension>(?:\.[a-z]{2,10}){1,2}))$
```

This will leave a `.` on the end of the subdomain (and on the start of the extensio)n, but you can use a `substr($string,0,-1)` or similar to remove that.

Expanded form for readability:

```
^
(?P<subdomains>
  (?:[\w-]+\.)*?
)
(?P<domain>
  [\w-]+
  (?P<extension>
     (?:\.[a-z]{2,10}){1,2}
   )
)$
```

(can add comments to explain any of that, if necessary?)

Comment: I'm afraid this is the result I'm getting still:

Array
(
    [0] => http://test.co.uk
    [scheme] => http
    [1] => http
    [login] => 
    [2] => 
    [pass] => 
    [3] => 
    [host] => test.co.uk
    [4] => test.co.uk
    [subdomain] => test
    [5] => test
    [domain] => co.uk
    [6] => co.uk
    [extension] => uk
    [7] => uk
)

It should also work with something like subdomain.subdomain2.test.co.uk

Comment: I think you can fix that by making the subdomain part lazy.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm still not quite getting a clean domain from this.

Answer (score 0):

parse_url() does not work to extract subdomains and domain name extensions.  You have to invent your own solution here.

I think a proper implementation would have to include a library of all domain name extensions, updated regularily.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/publicsuffix/list/master/public_suffix_list.dat