# Is space allowed in the <hierarchical part> of an URI?

Tags: c#

According to Wikipedia, URI is defined as

```
<scheme name> : <hierarchical part> [ ? <query> ] [ # <fragment> ]
```

I tried to pass "http://some site/page" to `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` and it returns false. I then tried "http://some%20site/page" , with the white space encoded. And still got false.

However, "http://somesite/page%20Zero" will give me True.

Can I draw the conclusion that in the "root level" of the  in a URI. Space is NOT allowed? Or there is something else I missed.

Comment: Wikipedia refers to complete specification - [RFC  3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) which is what you should read if you need to implement your own Uri verification or interested in precise details of what allowed and what is not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your break-down of a URI is overly simplified. The "hierarchical part" contains the `authority` and the `path`. The `authority` is further broken-down into optional username/password, hostname, and port details.

The `http://some site/page` URI has "some site" as the hostname component, which is invalid.

The `http://somesite/page zero` URI has "somesite" as the hostname, which is valid, and "page zero" as the path component, which is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

No, spaces are not allowed in the domain name part of the URL. See the details here

http://www.thesitewizard.com/domain/domain-name-with-spaces-or-dots.shtml

http://www.netregister.biz/faqit.htm#1

Answer (score 1):

The `hierarchical` part of the URI actually comprises the `authority` and the `path` components; see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) for details.

In particular, you'll see that the `path` component is essentially constructed from `pchars` which can be (among other things) "pct-encoded" characters, defined in [this section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), of which `%20` is an example.

---

I've posted a PHP solution to the problem of URI verification here, which could be of interest:

[How to make this PHP URL parsing function nearly perfect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277449/how-to-make-this-php-url-parsing-function-nearly-perfect/3277522#3277522)

The code *roughly* validates against RFC 3986, but makes some exceptions.

Comment: you recently approved the following wiki edit, which contained plagiarized text:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1047273#./1047273?&_suid=1353421584593017052236174415713.  In the future, please be more careful when reviewing tag wikis.